# Counting number of rows in mysql table of a particular id optimally

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I am using this code

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT section_id FROM forum_posts WHERE section_id='$sectionID'  ");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
```

to count the number of posts under specific category to show on the home page of the forum that how many posts are there in a particular section.
So is there a better option that to go through all the posts of that type. I think it will be a huge performance drain if I use this.

Edit 1: I just have to display the number of posts under each section in the forum so I want to check in the homepage how many topics each sections has as of now. 
What will be the optimal mysql query for it.

Edit 2: Should I replace teh mysql_query function as stated in the phpmanual?

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use count in sql itself.

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT count(post_id) as 'count_of_posts' FROM forum_posts WHERE section_id='$sectionID' ");
```

If you want to get all section counts at the same time you can do it this way:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT section_id, count(post_id) as 'count_of_posts' FROM forum_posts WHERE section_id='$sectionID' group by section_id");
```

Comment: Not sure there is a reason for distinct, group by unique section_id should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is more normal SQL, to count the rows using a COUNT() aggregate function. If you need to count several sections at once, then use GROUP BY. But you knew that, right?

Benchmark first, optimise second.

1. Load your test server (which must be production-spec) with a production-size load of data; configure all parameters the same as your production server.
2. Repeatedly run the code and time it.
3. If it does not seem to slow, you're finished.

My suggestions:

1. Explain the query. If it is running a full table scan, then add an index on Section ID. This should reduce the full table scan, at least to a full index scan. This may be still too slow.
2. If this is still too slow, consider caching the result somewhere. You can invalidate this cache when posts are added, deleted or moved to another section.
3. If the caching is inconvenient or doesn't work - for instance if you have a less than 90% hit rate on the cache, consider permanently storing the counts, and manually adjusting them. Then you don't need to recalculate the counts for a section when its posts haven't changed.

Suppose you have 1e9 posts, in 1e3 sections. Most of the time, most sections' posts won't change. So you can just modify the counts for the section(s) affected by an operation - for example, for add/delete, you just update one section, and for a move, two sections, leaving 998 sections' counts unmodified and avoiding expensive counting operations.

But I think it is highly unlikely that you have 1e9 posts (I'm sure Stackoverflow does not).

Consider investigating how Stack Overflow manages its tags-questions counts.

Comment: right now wiht around 10k post in forum_posts the query is being performed at 0.02 seconds. Can it be more optimised ?

Comment: If you want to count the rows, use a COUNT() query. Any further optimisation can probably wait.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT distinct section_id, count(section_id) as num_of_posts FROM forum_posts WHERE section_id='$sectionID' group by section_id`
then do a $num_of_rows = $sql1['num_of_posts'];

Or keeping your query as it is, do a `count($sql1)`;